# Mel/Python script for moving camera along (x,y) grid

Tags: python, matrix, camera, maya, mel

I am trying to create Mel or Python script for Maya, which would move the camera through a square matrix, row by row. It would be great to be able to enter the custom row/column value (N).

I sketched [an algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CBIM.jpg) I need, but sadly lack the knowledge to implement the code.

Any help on the code side would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: For this simple algorithm, the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) should suffice.

Comment: Some questions here: Why do you need to move it row by row? (There are some commands that move instantly to a specified position) Do you need to do any additionnal treatment at each step of the translation? How many custom row/column value are there?  (1 for x and 1 for y or only 1 custom value that applies for x and y ?) Your algorithm says that at the end, `x=y=N` but it can be simplified (You don't need the `x=N?` test)

Comment: Remember thank you is just a sentence. Reputation makes the site work.

Answer (score 2):

While [@BrendanAbels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547004/brendan-abel) answer is sound, it sidesteps what Maya is used for. Maya is used for animation, and as such you quite rarely want to move things in your code (this way, as it serves no purpose). What you instead want is that your code initiates a node structure that accomplishes what you want.

The advantage of building nodes is as follows:

1. Maya will build a GUI for you. A GUI that any competent Maya user knows how to operate modify and animate.
2. You can change the inner working of your structure later or animate the inputs.
3. This embeds your code in the Maya file so that it can be resumed later.

Ok, so how do we do this. There are several ways. We could use ramp and lookup nodes. Or we can do it the straight way and directly hook up a expression node. So what does this look like in mel:

```
addAttr -at long -sn N -k 1 persp;
addAttr -at long -sn Xmax -k 1 -min 1 -dv 10 persp;
addAttr -at long -sn Ymax -k 1 -min 1 -dv 10 persp;
expression -s ("translateX = N % Xmax;\r\n" +
               "translateY = ( (N - translateX)/Xmax ) % Ymax;")
           -o persp -uc all persp;
connectAttr time1.o persp.N; 
// eliminate prev line if you want to drive manually
```

Note how **persp** node has 3 new channels you can adjust. I hooked time to your node but you can hook up anything really. Driving it yourself allows you to do different things (or move the camera mid render pass if you wish).

Your being a bit opaque on what you want to use this for so hard to say anything more. Suffice to say we could have solved your entire problem form start to finish with less work, and it is extremely unlikely that your doing anything we haven't seen before.

Comment: the script works like a charm! I made a syntax error at the first attempt so I thought something is wrong, but everything works perfect! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

The main commands you'll want to use are [ls](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/ls.html), [xform](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/xform.html), [currentTime](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/currentTime.html), and [setKeyFrame](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/setKeyframe.html)

Here are the basics for a python script to set the transform positions.  You can use `currentTime` to change the time value and `setKeyFrame` to set keys.

This script expects you to have the camera transform node selected (ie. the first `ls` command).

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

nx = 10
ny = 10
cam = cmds.ls(selection=True)[0]

z = 0
for x in range(nx):
    for y in range(ny):
        cmds.xform(cam, worldSpace=True, translation=[x, y, z])
```